# VueJS: State from deleted component remains and affects the next one (sibling)

Tags: vuejs2

I have a notifications component that has some notifications item child components  that are fed from an array in the parent component. The child component has the ability to update and delete itself. It can mark itself as read when clicked. It will make a request to the server with Axios and then change a button icon to close (fa-close). Which works fine.

Now it can delete itself. When clicked it will send a delete request to the server, and when successful emit an event to the parent component to delete it from the array with splice. Now it works fine but the issue I'm having is that the new icon that I changed still remains for the next component (next item in the array). And that bugs me because I can't seem to find a way to make it display the initial icon which was initialize with the component.

here's some code if that can help

NotificationsItem.vue

```
<template>
    <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">
        <button class="pull-right"
            title="@lang('text.notifications.markAsRead')"
            @click="markAsReadOrDestroy">
                <i class="fa" :class="iconClass" v-show="!loading"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-lg fa-fw" v-show="loading"></i>
        </button>
        <!-- {{ notification.data }} -->
        I'm the index {{ index}} and the ID is {{notification.id}}
```

```
  <span class="hljs-tag">&lt;/<span class="hljs-name">li</span>&gt;</span>
```

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['notification', 'index'],
        data() {
            return {
                loading: false,
                icon: 'check',
                markedAsRead: false,
            }
        },
        computed: {
            iconClass() {
                return 'fa-' + this.icon;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            markAsReadOrDestroy() {
                if (this.markedAsRead) {
                    this.destroy();
                } else {
                    this.markAsRead();
                }
            },
            markAsRead() {
                let vm = this;
                this.loading = true;
                this.$http.patch('/notifications/markasread/' + this.notification.id)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        vm.loading = false
                        vm.markedAsRead = true
                        vm.icon = 'close'
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        vm.loading = false;
                    });
            },
            destroy() {
                let vm = this;
                this.loading = true;
                this.$http.delete('/notifications/' + this.notification.id)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        vm.loading = false;
                        vm.$emit('deleted', vm.index);
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                        vm.loading = false;
                    });
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Notifications Item mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>

NotificationsList.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="list-group">
        <notifications-item
            v-for="(notification, index) in notifications"
            :notification="notification"
            @deleted="remove"
            :index="index">
            {{ notification.data['text'] }}
        </notifications-item>
    </div>
</template>
```

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                notifications: notifications.data,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            remove(index) {
                console.log(index);
                this.notifications.splice(index, 1);
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Notifications List mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>

If anyone can help me that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `index` as paramter in `remove` function, like following:

```
    <notifications-item
        v-for="(notification, index) in notifications"
        :notification="notification"
        @deleted="remove(index)"
        :index="index">
        {{ notification.data['text'] }}
    </notifications-item>
```

Comment: Thanks! I found a fix by adding a key attribute on the child component with a unique value (the notification id). And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix by adding a key attribute on the child component with a unique value (the notification id). And that's it.